# Возможно ли добавить новую обрабатываемую точку входа не перезапуская webpack?

Tags: webpack

Я знаю, что `webpack` надо перезапускать каждый раз, когда мы меняем `webpack.config.js`. Но рарзработало ли сообщество webpack что-то, что позволяет добавить новую точку входа и заставить `webpack` её обработать без перезапуска `webpack`?

Если ответ отрицательный, то так и напишите.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, за чем это нужно?

Comment: @Igor Golovin, Из принципа  "Ни одного лишнего рутинного действия". Вообще, перезапуск приложения радь того, чтобы добавить новую страницу, кажется бредом в 21-ом веке. Можно в сочетании с gulp использовать `vynil-named`, но эта интеграция имеет серьёзные ограничения.